# Why normal map baking break at UV seams?

Tags: uv, texture-baking

I wonder why my normal map baking (from high to low mesh) got incorrect result like this:

[image]

[**blend file**](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/31869) is here. Thanks anyone that can explain or help to solve it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The results are correct. The reason it appears wrong is because the normal map is using [tangent space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space) (which is what you usually want) - tangent direction is based on the UV map, so there will usually be a difference in colour where there is a UV seam.

However the colour difference is not an artefact. When used as a normal map (not as a colour map), everything will display correctly:

[image]

(That's the low poly model)

Comment: Thanks Greg, I think it makes enough sense. Just one more thing, I found seam still occur when using Cycles, Did I do something wrong? http://www.pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=77977

Comment: Tried a bunch of things, couldn't get rid of that seam :( Using a 32 bit image didn't help.

Comment: I just tried new blank image with "32 bit float" toggled, it seems working fine. I don't know if this is something to be reported to official?

Comment: Weird, I tried that too and it made no difference. If that is indeed what solves it for you, then it's not a bug - using 8-bit images for normal mapping can introduce subtle artefacts like that.

Comment: Tried again, You are right. It did't help so much. And new problems found: 32 bit baking seems sort of brighter... I don't know why either. :(

Comment: It looks brighter because it's not gamma corrected. Blender assumes all 8-bit images are sRGB with a 2.2 gamma correction, and 16/32-bit images are linear with no gamma correction. Colour spaces are a rather complicated topic, blender handles it really nicely though.

Comment: That's why when using an 8-bit image for a normal map you have to set the image node to non-colour data, but with 32-bit images that option makes no difference (blender automatically interprets 32-bit images as non-color data in linear space)

Comment: Hi Greg, I've tried to expose it here, fyi. https://developer.blender.org/T42056

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally found a solution. I was having the same trouble, when clicking through the various texture options I clicked on Normal Map, which is found in the Image Sampling tad under the texture options. Clicking this instantly sorted the normal map out so there's no seams showing. Maybe it will work for you too. Hope you get it sorted!

Comment: Normal Map option under in the Image Sampling rollout present only for Blender Internal allows engine to treat the image as normal map which is not the same as color map. It doesn't help to correct seams on the normal map nor they are any problem themselves.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a bug with the Texture node and Color Space unchangeable then, before you bake:

Create New texture in UV Editor - Unwrap your Model - On "N-panel" go to bottom and change ColorSpace to NonColor. And now bake nomalMap.