# How do I clear the normal map seams even though I painted over the texture?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, normal-map

UPD: The answer was that I had to set the normal map as Non-color.

I have an altar model that I want to texture. I have visible seams, but I paint over them. It appears correct when a map is in the Color node (diff/normal). I save the painted over image, but when I reload as Normal Map Color node, the seams are there, and they are pretty obvious. I've done the same with the normal map (just smudging the seams but it does appear seamless when the map is in Color). Any clues?
[image: As Color]

[image: As Normal]

Comment: Seams in the normal map are caused by usage of UV map when calculating tangent space, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16354/why-normal-map-baking-break-at-uv-seams. In general they shouldn't be painted over.

Comment: The seams are being caused by some problem in the implementation of the normal map, or by some problem in the baking.  There aren't any details for either of those in this question that would allow us to diagnose which.  I realize this is now 5 years old and that the problem is long resolved or abandoned, but I'm voting to delete this question because of a lack of details necessary to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Open it in GIMP.
Filters > Map > **Make Seamless**
File > Export As > Whatever_you_want_to_call_it.png

Export > uncheck everything > Compression level 9 > Export
Load this normal map w/ node editor, in place of the original.

Comment: It may soften the details.  If that happens, load original as a new layer > select all > feather a decent amount > then delete, so it has crisp details inside, and a seamless outer edge.

Comment: The feather amount will depend on your normal-map size.  30 or 50 pixels may do.

Comment: My map is not a seamless one, it's one exported for a unique prop. It uses unwrapped UVs that do not go past the edge of the image.

Comment: I know it's not seamless.  Gimp can fix that.  It blends the edges so they line up when it wraps.

Comment: It creates an interesting solution, where it doesn't actually add up (the edges do not line up) but it is really soft, so there's no visible seam. It'll have to do, thanks!

Comment: Oh yeah I didn't imagine circular UV bounds for cylinders when I read that.  Didn't get what you were saying there.  Using a different projection, cube for instance, could fix it, but that might take some tweaking to line it up again.